# Is there any way to create a drill-through graph/table using apache-superset(version 2.0.0)

Tags: apache-superset

I am using apache-superset. Is there any option to create a drill down or drill through from one dashboard to another?

Preset, which uses Apache Superset, has implemented a feature for Drilling to Chart details. Is there any option available in apache-superset?